# Why do I need to add my app's built Info.plist location to install Crashlytics in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Crashlytics installation process say:

**Xcode 10 only: Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build Phase's Input Files field:** `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

But it doesn't explain why this is needed. Does anyone know how this effects Crashlytics? I understand it's for passing in files, but it doesn't seem `Fabric/run` reads the file.

Comment: It might read it for API keys, it might add stuff to it, it might just "copy" it to another location, etc.. You never know until you check the script that is using it I guess.

Comment: I think when it runs that upload executable or something, that executable reads it..

Comment: @Brandon I found somewhere someone mentioned an out of order issue and this may have forced the ordering of the build phases. The executable doesn't read it.

Comment: also, would be good if anyone could show example, how it should look loke.

Comment: why is it prefiled with $(SRCROOT) in xcode and even in the firebase docs if we don't need $(SRCROOT) ?